# UITableView don't react on a tap

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a fully working grouped tableview. But when i just tap on a cell - nothing happens. willSelectRowAtIndexPath is not even being called. All outlets are set correctly, userInteractions are enabled, tableView is the only view on a page. Googling for hours made no success. Everyone has a selection feature from the begining and someone even tries to ged rid of it. Help, please.

Code (bad one, i know):

```
//
//  VKFriendsPage.m
//  vKontakte
//
//  Created by ASPCartman on 3/29/10.
//  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "VKFriendsPage.h"
#import "UIImage+Resize.h"
#import "VKProfilePage.h"


@implementation VKFriendsPage
@synthesize friends,onlineFriends,VKId,connection,avatarCache;
-(void) didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    NSLog(@" Memary Wornenk!!! OLOLOLOLOL!");
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    table.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    if ([connection.myVkontakteID isEqual:VKId]) {
        friends=[connection.myVKProfile friendsAll];
        onlineFriends=[connection.myVKProfile friendsOnline];

    }
    self.avatarCache = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
    queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    table.allowsSelection=YES;
}
#pragma mark Table Data Source Protocol Implementation

//Количество строк в секции
//0ая - Ребята онлайн
//1ая - Все
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) {
        return [onlineFriends count];
    }else if (section==1) {
        return [friends count];
    }else {
        return 0;
    }


}
//Создание клеток
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Инит клетки
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"FriendCell"];
    //Выбор секции
    NSArray *currentMan;
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        currentMan=[onlineFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else if (indexPath.section==1)
    {
        currentMan=[friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else {
        currentMan=nil;
    }
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text=[currentMan objectAtIndex:1];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"TODO: Статусы...";

    if ([avatarCache objectForKey:[currentMan objectAtIndex:2]]==nil) {
        NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:indexPath,@"Path",[currentMan objectAtIndex:2],@"URLString",nil];

        NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                selector:@selector(fetchAvatar:)
                                                                                  object:dic];

        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"profileIco" ofType:@"jpg"]]];
        [queue addOperation:operation];
        [operation autorelease];
    }else {
        [cell.imageView setImage:[avatarCache objectForKey:[currentMan objectAtIndex:2]]];
    }




    return [cell autorelease];
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return indexPath;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VKProfilePage *profilePage=[[VKProfilePage alloc] init];
    profilePage.title=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
    profilePage.connection=connection;  
    NSString *VKID;
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        VKID=[[onlineFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
    }else if (indexPath.section==1) {
        VKID=[[friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    profilePage.profile=[connection getProfileOf:VKID];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profilePage animated:YES];
    [profilePage release];
}


-(void)fetchAvatar:(NSDictionary *)dic
{
    NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dic objectForKey:@"URLString"]]];
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImage *resizedImage = [image thumbnailImage:70 transparentBorder:0 cornerRadius:5 interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
    [avatarCache setObject:resizedImage forKey:[dic objectForKey:@"URLString"]];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateRow:) withObject:[dic objectForKey:@"Path"] waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)updateRow:(NSIndexPath *) ip
{
    [table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    return NO;
};
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) {
        return @"Online";
    }else {
        return @"Offline";
    }
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return nil;
};
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement something like this in your `UITableView` delegate?

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}
```

Sorry, wrong assumption and a compiler warning ignored...

This is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiments and found the property `isUserInteractionEnabled` on the `UITableView` `View` ancestor. If set to `NO`, the cell selection is disabled (as is any other interaction). In this case it is impossible to move the views cells up and down.